# Override empty methods in inheritance

Tags: c#, oop

Need a bit of OOP help.

I have a base payment consisting of `SendPayment() UpdateRecord()` then child classes implementing different payment formats e.g. PayPal, SagePay.

While all have `SendPayment()` method they are all implemented differently. So I override the base class to apply my own implementation in each child class. The base classes do not hold any implementation just empty methods. Is this a good way of OOP to have empty methods then implement override code in each child class or remove the empty methods in the base and have these methods in the child classes?

thanks...

Sorry a quick edit. I do use the base class for certain scenarios for example calculation. This covers all payment types such as counting how many products by the cost and removing records from the table.

Comment: If you don´t need to instantiate the base class, I would set your base class to be abstract and the same for your empty methods. This allows you to define an empty method and forces you to override it in derived classes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest to make your base class as `abstract` class and make the unimplemented method as `abstract` method.

```
    public abstract class BasePayment {

        //abstract method: unimplemented        
        public abstract void sendPayment();

        //implemented method    
        public void UpdateRecord(){
            .....
        }

    }
```

`Abstract` class is meant for this kind of scenarios where you want to have mix of implemented and unimplemented method. One added advantage here is: Every extending class will be forced to implement its own `sendPayment` method.

Comment: abstract, or even an Interface (if there is no code at all) is the OOP's way to go

Comment: @SteveB Agree. I believe OP wanted only `sendPayment` to be different hence thought `abstract` class is better option.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I think abstract is the correct way to go as I do mix and match. You are right SteveB I made a mistake and only the payment method is different. All methods are shared but the base has other implementations that are not used in the child classes.

Answer (score 2):

If your child classes doesn't have meaning without overriding base methods, keep base methods `abstract`.

But if base class contains only abstract methods, and doesn't have any state(which is your case I guess) is is better to use interface, because interface leave implementer right to have another base class

Answer (score 0):

It's OK. But it depends on how would you use the base class. You may mark methods or class `abstract` and in this case all child classes MUST implement them. If you mark them as `virtual` child classes may override them if required or leave empty. 
If you don't specify methods in base class you won't be able to use abstraction and polymorphism with all it power. For example if you have list of Payments (`List<Payment>`) (doesn't matter what actual type of payment is) and you want to send all of them you won't be able to do next:

```
foreach(Payment payment in payments)
{
   payment.SendPayment();
}
```